# Git setup - Terminal Emulator for Git Bash

Tags: android, git, bash, ionic-framework

I'm running git 2.8.1 Setup, I want to be careful with this since I will be developing mobile apps.  I'm at the part where it's asking "Which terminal emulator do you want to use with your Git Bash?" And with choices of the following:

- Use MinTTY(the default terminal of MSYS2)
- Use Windows' default console window

Which is the best choice for me if I'm running a Windows 7 x64 Operating system and will be developing mobile applications? And if by any chance can someone explain their difference(s) or send a link for information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, you should use `MinTTY` regardless of other stuff. Even `MiTTY` has no advantage, windows' default console window('cmd') has lots of disadvantages. `cmd` has a very limited default history scroll-back stack and terrible font encoding and so forth. By contrast, `MinTTY` has resizeable window and other useful configurable options that could be open through right-click on toolbar of `git-bash`.

Comment: I also recommend MinTTY.

Answer (score 4):

First choice will not add git commands to your PATH environment variable, you need open a MSYS2 terminal to execute git in terminal.

For second choice, you can use git commands in your windows default console.

Beside, the most different matter I think is that, `windows' default console` use `\` as path separator, `MSYS2` use `/`.

Comment: Git's MinTTY terminal emulator option now also set PATH environment variables. Just restart your VS Code (or whatever terminal that you use) and type `git --version`.