# VS Code Error: spawn git ENOENT

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I get the error `Error: spawn git ENOENT` when I try to view git history using https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode on VS Code.. I'm very new to VS Code and github. I tried googling for solutions but I only found links about node.js which I don't understand at all..

Comment: What command did you use to try to view git history?

Comment: Do you have `git` installed?

Comment: I also had this error when using [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/). The extension had the remote URL wrong for some reason, as it was set to a URL that Git didn't actually have as a remote. I disabled and reenabled the extension, which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 17):

We need [to install Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) to use the Git History (git log) extension in VS Code.

Otherwise we will see this when running `git log`.

[image]

If you have already installed Git, then make sure that it is available from the shell, for example by typing `git --version`.

Once you have Git installed properly, you will see this when running `git log`.

[image]

Comment: I have been using github for desktop until now. I have git version 2.11.0.windows.3 according to `git --version` command from git shell. but I still get the error..

Comment: It's a shame that when you click "Dependencies" for Git History in Visual Studio Code, that it does not say please also install Git.  This can be killer for newcomers who are trying to learn the system.

Comment: I am getting this error from within VS Code when running a certain npm install module. This is the first time I have noticed this error, but as yet I do not have GIT installed. I would not have imagined GIT is a requirement to install modules...  I could be wrong here.

Comment: I just installed the latest version of Git, but still the same, PATH environment variable has not been set. This could be due to that, we choose to use [MinTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905283/git-setup-terminal-emulator-for-git-bash) during the Git installation.

Comment: **UPDATE:** Git's MinTTY terminal emulator option now also set PATH environment variables. Just restart your VS Code (or whatever terminal that you use) and type `git --version`.

Answer (score 10):

That means **you need to set environment variable in system for `git`**. After you set it well, the issue will disapper.

If your `OS` is Windows:

Try typing "git --version" in the system command line (do not use `git bash` by mistake). If you cannot see the version, it indicates that `git` is not added to the environment variables.

For example, my `Git` is installed on the disk "C:\", I need to add "C:\Program Files\Git" to the path of the `environment variables`.

**Method 1:**

**Steps:**

**Edit environment variables** -> **System Variables**

Edit `Path`,
add

```sh
;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
```

to current value of `Path` (remove the beginning `;` if redundant).

You need to adjust this file path according to your actual directory where git is installed.

Then restart your command line, and then try typing "git --version" again. If you can see python version now, try your vs code again, the issue you metioned will disappear.

**Another method:**

Reinstall your visual studio code with checking `"Add to PATH (available after restart)"`.
[image: add vscode to path]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue on MacOS (running VS Cod 1.26.1). With difference to other info that I had found, I worked only after setting:

```
 "git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"
```

No success setting the path to null or any other.

Comment: I wasted HOURS on this. Thank you so much, that was the only thing that worked for me on Mac.

Answer (score 3):

In Mac OS you have to modify your settings.json. For me currently located in Users//Library/Application Support/Code/user/settings.json

or what it is the same ~/Library/Application Support/Code/user/settings.json

There set "git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git",

You can achieve the same inside Visual Studio Code going to the "Settings" Gear Icon > Settings Then search for git. Under Extensions go to Git and look for Path Click on Edit in settings.json
It will open the same file inside the editor

[See the image for VSCODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUSY7.png)

Comment: You can access this without trouble by going to "Settings" then typing "git path" in the searchbar. But thanks for the tip 

Answer (score 3):

I just got this error while trying to use the **Worktrees** tab from the GitLens extension. With `git worktree list` I found out I had some `prunable` worktrees, so it worked again after I ran this:

```
git worktree prune
```

Answer (score 0):

install git, and run `git init`

If you are getting this error from a React app created using Create React App, i.g. `create-react-app nameOfYourApp`, you need to setup CircleCI environment. More info here https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/running-tests

On your own environment

**Windows (cmd.exe)**

`set CI=true&&npm test`

`set CI=true&&npm run build`

(Note: the lack of whitespace is intentional.)

**Windows (Powershell)**

`($env:CI = "true") -and (npm test)`

`($env:CI = "true") -and (npm run build)`

**Linux, macOS (Bash)**

`CI=true npm test`

`CI=true npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an edge case, but I had purged VSCode from my system, and removed the `.vscode` and `$HOME/.config/Code` directories. However, I was unaware that GitLens creates a `$HOME/.config/GitKraken` directory and had left that intact.

After reinstalling VSCode and GitLens, the newer installation of GitLens was misconfigured by the residual directory and VSCode threw the original poster's error. Repeating the uninstall and including all relevant directories solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYyEe.png)

Everything is fine after uninstalling gitlens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).